# Can absolute scalability be 'relaxed' to an equivalent condition in the properties of a norm?

Tags: normed-spaces

All norms on a vector space $V$ must satisfy for any $x\in V$

$$\Vert \alpha x \Vert = \vert \alpha \vert \Vert x \Vert $$
for any scalar $\alpha\in R$.

However, I've been told that an equivalent condition is $$\Vert \alpha x \Vert \leq \vert \alpha \vert \Vert x \Vert .$$

Is this true, or is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relaxed condition also implies $$ \left\|\frac1\alpha \alpha x\right\|\le\left|\frac1\alpha\right|\|\alpha x\|$$
and hence 
$$ \|\alpha x\|\le |\alpha|\|x\|\le |\alpha|\left|\frac1\alpha\right|\|\alpha x\|=\|\alpha x\|,$$
which implies equality throughout.